# log4net appenders to database with different bufferSize

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I have two loggers for same database with different level. I would like to have different bufferSize for each logger.
One way is to have two appenders to same database with only difference in bufferSize element, but it's copy-paste.
Is it possible to extend already defined appender and change it's bufferSize property?
For example:

```
 <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="20" />
      ...other elements
</appender>
<appender name="AdoNetAppenderChild" extends="AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1" />
</appender>

    <logger name="Fatal" additivity="false">
  <level value="FATAL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppenderChild" />
</logger>
    <logger name="Common" additivity="false">
  <level value="INFO"/>
  <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
</logger>
```

What I want to avoid is having two appenders with same elements and properties and only different value is bufferSize

Comment: _"it's copy-paste"_ Config very often is, as well as being annoyingly verbose and repetitive.. In this situation doubling up in the config is probably your best bet though - you really don't want to change the buffer size at runtime, and the only other alternative is to write code to duplicate the appender (or create a new one etc), which then needs to be documented, tested etc.

Comment: Thanks.
One more question, is it save to have single static logger for every MVC controller and in that logger add some extra information from session.
Specificly, if I put log4net.LogicalThreadContext.["sessionVariable"] from session, can I be sure it won't get overwritten or should on every request create new logger instance?

Comment: I wouldn't be 100% confident about that with a static logger. log4net caches loggers so creating a new on on each request would be safer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make one appender and use a evaluator to log when you have an error message:

```
<evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
    <threshold value="ERROR"/>
</evaluator>
```

> The Evaluator is a pluggable object that is used by the
>   BufferingAppenderSkeleton to determine if a logging event should not
>   be buffered, but instead written/sent immediately. If the Evaluator
>   decides that the event is important then the whole contents of the
>   current buffer will be sent along with the event. Typically an
>   SmtpAppender will be setup to buffer events before sending as the cost
>   of sending an email may be relatively high. If an important event
>   arrives, say an ERROR, we would like this to be delivered immediately
>   rather than waiting for the buffer to become full. This is where the
>   Evaluator comes in as it allows us to say: "when an important event
>   arrives don't worry about buffering, just send over everything you
>   have right now".